# node js and mysql convert number with comma to float

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i have a json Array which contains parsed numbers (in this Format: 12345,012) I want to save it to my mySQL db table.

Right now my function insert the number to my table like this => 12345.000.

my query looks like that:

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO mytable SET ?', jsonArray, callback);
```

So what should I change? My jsonArray contains numbers so I cannot .replace the comma to dot.

```
My jsonArray:             My Table:              I want this Values:
12345,012                  12345.000              12345.012
23456,123                  23456.000              23456.123
```

Edit: My table columns are = **float(20,5)**

Edit2: The json Array is an object :

```
{ id: 'kdsnad0123',
  value1: '0',
  value2: '0',
  value3: '251,4331',
  value4: '5,51135',
  value5: '6,74677',
  value6: '110'
}{ id: 'kdsnad0124',
  value1: '10',
  value2: '660',
  value3: '251,4331',
  value4: '4,4235',
  value5: '3,727',
  value6: '10'
}...
```

comming from a csv file and inserted with an foreach to my table:

```
  async.forEach(jsonArrayObject, function (jsonArray, callback) {
           conn.query('INSERT INTO mytable SET ?', jsonArray, callback);
           console.log(jsonArray);
```

Comment: What is the data type of jsonArray returned by `typeof jsonArray `? The reason for asking is that JSON describes the syntax of a string representing an object. If the array is an "object" it does not contain "parsed values" of type number containing string values like "12345,012". So where are they?

Comment: Please post more of your code, including a console.log of your jsonArray

Comment: added additional code and console.log

Comment: Could you please confirm the "valuex" properties are of type string, as shown in the log, and if so whether you still need further assistance?

Comment: no the values aren't Strings. I tryed to replace the comma (,) with a dot (.), with .replace function and get and error. (Number cannot .replace...need string)

Comment: my solution (atm) = I created an caching table where i insert all values as varchar. After he inserted all values to my cached table, I get all values > convert it > Save it to mySQL table

Answer (score 0):

my "sollution" for that is create a function like this

```
function castStringToFloat(number) {
let numberString = number.replace(",", ".");
return parseFloat(numberString);}
```